# Calling function when user taps anywhere on screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

In my app I have a small menu I made which is basically a UIView with two button on it. The menu opens when the user taps a button and closes also when the user taps the same button. I'd like the menu to close when the user taps anywhere outside of the menu UIView.

The menu:

[image: I'd like this menu to be closed.]

Comment: add tapgesture for your view,

Comment: you could add a transparent overlay behind the menu and on that overlay you could add a tap gesture recognizer and close the menu in its selector funciton

Comment: Adding a tap gesture to your view is better than everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that when you show the small menu, add below it a invisible button (UIColor.clear) with the entire screen as a frame. And it's action is to dismiss the menu of yours.

Make sure when you dismiss the small menu to dismiss thus button as well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can also apply this easy way

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapBlurButton(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


        func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            if //checkmenuopen
            {
                closemenuhere
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use basically touches began function

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("TAPPED SOMEWHERE ON VIEW")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to your case:

**1-** Implementing [*`touchesBegan(_:with:)`*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan) method in your ViewController:

> Tells this object that one or more new touches occurred in a view or
>   window.

Simply, as follows:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // do something
}
```

**2-** Add a [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer) to the main view of your ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doSomething(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func doSomething(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("do something")
}
```

Or -of course- you could implement the selector without the parameter:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doSomething))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func doSomething() {
    print("do something")
}
```

**3-** You could also follow [Mohammad Bashir Sidani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45629722/5501940).

I would suggest to make sure add the appropriate constraints to your button whether it has been added programmatically or by storyboard.

Comment: So the story is that at first I did add the touchesBegan() method but it did not execute for some reason. So that's why I asked you folks on StackOverflow.

Comment: I see, I would suggest to mention it in the question then. Anyway, the good thing is problem has been solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the code below will work in your case, just a advice.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var closeMenuGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    closeMenuGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(closeMenu))
    closeMenuGesture.delegate = self

    // or closeMenuGesture.isEnable = false
  }

  @IBAction func openMenu() {
    view.addGestureRecognizer(closeMenuGesture)
    // or closeMenuGesture.isEnabled = true
  }

  @IBAction func closeMenu() {
    view.removeGestureRecognizer(closeMenuGesture)
    // or closeMenuGesture.isEnabled = false
  }

}

extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return touch.view === self.view // only valid outside menu UIView
  }
}
```

And I never be in this situation so not sure making enable/disable  closeMenuGesture is enough to ensure other controls work normally, or to add/remove closeMenuGesture is more insured.